# Excel: Most frequent value/word in a not-continous range

Tags: excel

I need to find the most frequent word (categorical text, e.g."T2") in a row, but not across all columns. If the range was continous I would attempt something like:

```
=INDEX(B3;M3,MODE(MATCH(B3;M3,B3;M3,0)))
```

However, I'm doing this for multiple variables and don't want to make a separate subset sheet/file for each one so hope this is possible. I'm attempting to use the following formula but get an error message that hightlights the MODE function:

```
=INDEX((B3;F3;J3),MODE(MATCH(B3;F3;J3,B3;F3;J3,0)))
```

My data looks something like this:

```
    person A                        person B                        person C            
ID  Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4
1   T2      C1      N       f       T2      C1      N       f       T4      C9      Y       e
2   T4      C5      Y       b       T4      C1      Y       b       T2      C1      N       e
3   T2      C2      N       g       T4      C5      Y       d       T2      C1      N       f
4   T4      C9      Y       e       T4      C1      Y       b       T2      C1      N       e
5   T1      C2      N       b       T2      C2      N       h       T2      C2      N       g
6   T4      C9      Y       b       T4      C1      Y       b       T4      C9      Y       f
7   V2      C1      Y       c       V6      C2      N       c       T2      C2      N       h
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqdDe.png)

And the result I want is to add a column to the end that gives me the most common value/name, exapmle for Var1:

```
ID  Mode_Var1
1   T2
2   T4
3   T2
4   T4
5   T2
6   T4
7   NA
```

Am I on the right track? Is this possible using Index, Mode and Match? Is there another way if this doesn't work? Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Added table (same as in image), made range in first example correspond to example data

Comment: There's no data to copy/paste and the columns in your sample function don't seem to match with the data in your image, so it's a little hard to figure out what you're looking for. Can you provide a small amount of sample data, the formula you are attempting (only within that data), and the result you desire?

Comment: Tried to fix that now :)

Answer (score 1):

You would use a countif in an array form of INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(B2:M2,MATCH(MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN(B2:M2),4)=2,COUNTIF(B2:M2,B2:M2))),IF(MOD(COLUMN(B2:M2),4)=2,COUNTIF(B2:M2,B2:M2)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Put this formula in N2, press Ctrl-Shift-Enter, then copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Tried again for the example data and now it works! Just hope it will work on the actual data set too...

Comment: I don't really understand how this formula works so I was wondering if I could ask a follow up: What in the formula specifies which column to look at? When I apply it to my actual data, it sums the most frequent over alle the columns, not the one I want... 
Also, in the MOD parts, why divide by 4? And what does the =2 mean?

Comment: MOD() is what tells the formula which columns to use.  Your data had a pattern of every four columns.  It returns the remainder, so 6/4 equals 1 with a remainder of 2.  MOD would return 2.  So the 2 is the remainder and the first column in which the wanted data is found.  In this case it was column B or the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Given a setup as shown, use this **array formula*** in cell B13 and copy over and down:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($B$3:$M$9,MATCH($A13,$A$3:$A$9,),0),MODE(IFERROR(MATCH(INDEX($B$3:$M$9,MATCH($A13,$A$3:$A$9,),0),IF($B$2:$M$2=B$12,INDEX($B$3:$M$9,MATCH($A13,$A$3:$A$9,),0)),0),-COLUMN($B$3:$M$9))))
```

The `#N/A` results mean that there was no most frequent entry for that ID and Var (all three had different entries).  If you want to put something else there,wrap the formula in an IFERROR.

[image: tigeravatar example for Eva]

*Array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  When done correctly, the formula will be surrounded by curly braces `{=formula}`, those are added automatically so don't try to add them manually.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. I still can't get it to work though. I get a  circular reference warning and the result in B13 is 0 :/ 
Also I noted that we use different separators(my; is your , I think) and I tried to correct for that but not sure if that may be the cause.

Comment: @Eva The circular reference means you are trying to include the active cell in your formula calculation, which should not be the case.  Verify your ranges, and move the formula to a different cell if necessary to avoid confusion.  As for the separators, simply replace all `,` with `;` as you've surmised.